# Add default value to a migration of another column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3, default-value, rails-migrations

Since the updated_at column looks at all attributes when updated I want to add a new_updated_at which I will decide when it updates.

The default value on insertion via migration I want it to be the current updated_at.

How do I set the default value of the migration to be the value of the same row but of another column?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you have to do the initialization by hand, a quick bit of SQL in your `up` migration will take care of it:

```
def up
    # Add the new column...
    connection.execute('update models set new_updated_at = updated_at')
end
```

You'll have to replace `models` with your real table name of course.

You might need to modify the generated migration and split it into separate `up` and `down` methods but that shouldn't be a problem. If you don't want to do that, write a separate migration to initialize `new_updated_at` and put the above `connection.execute` call into that migration's `up` method.